# Environment variable

Tags: python, virtualenv, tox

I have a `tox.ini` file like this:

```
[tox]
envlist =
    {py27,py34}

[testenv]
setenv =
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements-test.txt
commands =
    nosetests -v --stop --with-coverage --cover-package=project
```

So, I need to pass to my tox env an environment variable from my SO. This variable is private and changes according to the environment.

How I do it?

Comment: Could you let us know what you've tried so far?

Comment: @GavinSchulz I try:
    [testenv]
    setenv =
        VAR=$VAR

Comment: Did you try: ``ENV="foo" tox``?

Comment: @JamesMills I need to run this on Travis too, so, this approach doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesMills I try your suggestion locally, but doesn't work.

Comment: So your tests are depending on some configuration parameter you want to pass through to nose via env var?

Comment: @JamesMills my application needs some env vars. This vars are private and changes according to the environment, so, I can't put this values fixed on "setenv" session. Run tests without tox is OK.

Comment: I'd probably then invert the problem and save the configuration parameters you need to use in a file that your application can read from which your test setup can write to initially.

Comment: @JamesMills the environment variables is private, but project is public. I can't push it, today I set values on Travis environment settings.

Comment: Do you're probably doing integration testing against a 3rd-party "cloud" service of some kind; e.g: Twitter API and storing API Token/Secret. Hmmm :)

Comment: @JamesMills Thats it !!! Excuse me for not being able to express myself well.

Comment: Yeah I can't really think of a *good way* to do this really; except that "don't" :) Testing 3rd-party services is really not all taht useful really IHMO.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution! Tox 2.0 has a settings called [passenv](https://testrun.org/tox/latest/config.html?highlight=passenv#confval-passenv=SPACE-SEPARATED-GLOBNAMES)

> A list of wildcard environment variable names which shall be copied from the tox invocation environment to the test environment. If a specified environment variable doesn’t exist in the tox invocation environment it is ignored. You can use * and ? to match multiple environment variables with one name.
>   Note that the PATH and PIP_INDEX_URL variables are unconditionally passed down and on Windows SYSTEMROOT, PATHEXT, TEMP and TMP will be passed down as well whereas on unix TMPDIR will be passed down. You can override these variables with the setenv option.